# Using a version number suffix to prevent image caching

Tags: html, image, caching

Is there any reason why it would be a bad idea to append a version number to the src attribute of an image to prevent caching? For example:

```
<img alt='Test' src='images/cat.png?v=1.456'/>
```

On repeat browser visits the image is cached until the version number changes. The version number would be updated only when these particular graphics have been changed.

Is this valid markup and a sensible technique?

Comment: Yup! its perfectly ok... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is valid markup and it's a simple, straightforward technique to achieve the desired result in most cases.

However, the correct solution would be to use appropriate HTTP cache control headers together with the image resource instead. The [`ETag`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) header in particular is designed to solve this exact problem.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I will take a look into cache control headers and the ETag header.